# ExpandableListView not showing up in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I am facing one issue,I am inflating my fragment using `inflater.inflate(id, container, false)`. If I inflate it using `inflater.inflate(id, null)` then it is showing up.

I can't use second method for inflating as I have defined `theme` in `manifest` file and need a different background for this specific screen. After using second method, background image is not covering complete screen.

Please find below my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/home_blackgroundpng"
android:orientation="vertical" >
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/divider_color1" >
            </View>
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"                        
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" >
        <include layout="@layout/report_header"/>
        </LinearLayout>
                <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/divider_color1" >
            </View>
            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/reportList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Code to inflate it is:

```
public class SalesReportSTLFragment  extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_stl, container, false);
        fillList();
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: paste some code please.

Comment: Information you've provided is not enough to say anything. Post at least your onCreateView code.

Comment: I have used custom adapter but issue is coming only with the inflate method.

Comment: Why is `root` a `ViewGroup` and not just a `View`? Try `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_stl, container, false);`

Comment: @Randy, that doesn't make any difference.